# Displaying bivariate symbology legend in ArcGIS Online as grid

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I'm super excited by the recently added bivariate symbology in ArcGIS Pro. However, when publishing maps and layers, I noticed the legend for my 4x4 grid changes into 16 different lines in the online legend. Not perfect.

Does anyone know of a way to show the legend in ArcGIS Online as it is shown in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using bivariate symbology in AGOL already does this, though it may not automatically pick it up during publishing. Just go to the layer's **Visualization** settings once it's published and recreate the bivariate symbology.

[image: bivariate symbol]

Comment: This seems to not work for me - I recreated the style but when I click legend it is still showing lines. Could this be because I am applying it to a line feature class? Or would there be another reason?